# When i try to edit any product in magento admin, i get redirected to dashboard

Tags: magento, redirect, save, admin, dashboard

I have seen that many people faced this issue. It happened all of a sudden and the suggested solution is to set "Add Secret Key to URLs" in admin->security to "No". I have done that and still the issue persists. Whenever i try to edit anything in a product in admin and click on "save" or "save and continue edit", i get redirected to dashboard and nothing gets updated in the product. Please help!

Comment: Do you have any custom modules installed? Which version of Magento are you using?

Comment: I think you have some custom work that affects product save and throwing exception that is why you get redirected to dashboard. You can find exception in var/report.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?